# How can I search for a selected word in the entire document and highlight it?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am not familiar with VBA at all.

I want to search for text I select (rather than a given list of words or typing that text in a box), and then change its format (preferably make it bold or change its color).

I tried to change a few macros that I found.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: Everything you want is right here: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/macro-trick-how-to-highlight-multiple-search-strings-in-a-word-document/, including code you might later ask to customize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VBA code for this can be rather simple. For example:

```
Sub MakeBold()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    .Text = Selection.Text
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For PC macro installation & usage instructions, see: http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm

For Mac macro installation & usage instructions, see: https://wordmvp.com/Mac/InstallMacro.html

Comment: This is really helpful, Macropod! I can perhaps change the formatting values in this script.  The script I ended up with was nowehere near this one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.  Copy/paste into your VB editor window.

```
Sub HighlightWords()

Dim Word As Range
Dim WordCollection(2) As String
Dim Words As Variant

'Define list.
'If you add or delete, change value above in Dim statement.
WordCollection(0) = "you"
WordCollection(1) = "or"
WordCollection(2) = "Word document"

'Set highlight color.
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
'Clear existing formatting and settings in Find feature.
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
'Set highlight to replace setting.
Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True
'Cycle through document and find words in collection.
'Highlight words when found.

For Each Word In ActiveDocument.Words
    For Each Words In WordCollection
        With Selection.Find
        .Text = Words
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this response. I wanted to select a word and change its format, rather than using a predefined set of words. Macropod's answer was brilliant and it solved the issue very fast. But thanks anyway! Very appreciated!